# Shopify: remove whitespace foorloop

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a simple foorloop to output how many variants are in each line item; however the `| rstrip` does not seem to work at all!

Here is my for loop

```
{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
     {{line_item.variant_id | rstrip}} 
     {%- unless forloop.last == true  -%},{%- endunless -%}          
{% endfor %}
```

But still that outputs variants with an ending whitespace of each variants as in this example:

> 11111111111(whitespace)22222222222(whitespace)33333333333(whitespace)

Or as in

> 11111111111 22222222222 33333333333

Comment: Add `{%- -%}` to your forloop and endforloop.

Comment: Yes, but still it is not complete. Thanks! I will post how I solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In liquid, you can in fact do without filters. If you just add both `{%- -%}`and`{- -}` all white spaces between values will be removed. Given the example above, the whitespace issue has been solved by replacing it with the following:

```
{%- for line_item in order.line_items -%}
     {{-line_item.variant_id-}} 
     {%- unless forloop.last == true  -%},{%- endunless -%}          
{%- endfor -%}
```